# How to receive NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification iphone

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

After a lot of searching I was not able to find whether you need to pass a dictionary object to:

```
[NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification addObserver: forKeyPath: options: context:];
```

and what should be provided in options if I want to be notified for even a single change in the userDefaults. Also what is keypath?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` is just a notification that is sent out when the defaults are changed. To listen out for it you need this code :

```
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(defaultsChanged:)  
                   name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
                 object:nil];
```

This will call the method defaultsChanged: when the notification is fired. You need to implement this method like this :

```
- (void)defaultsChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Get the user defaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = (NSUserDefaults *)[notification object];

    // Do something with it
    NSLog(@"%@", [defaults objectForKey:@"nameOfThingIAmInterestedIn"]);
}
```

Comment: It is important to remove the observer in the dealloc method. If a destroyed class is still registered as an observer, the app will crash upon notification. Use: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

Comment: This throws an error. Someone might be staring at it for 15 minutes wondering what they did wrong to find out the "notification" is spelled wrong. Just an FYI

Comment: @deanWombourne: in defaultsChanged, where you say "// Do stuff in here!" How do you get at the information in the notification? It doesn't have userInfo, says the class reference.

Comment: userInfo is anything that the initial sender of the notification wanted to give to you - in this case it's `nil`. The other bit of information you get is `notification.object` which is the sender of the notification. See my edited answer for an example ;)

Comment: @deanWombourne Is there a way to know which user default has changed?

Comment: will this be called for any NSUserdefaults container? or just for standarduserdefaults?

Comment: @SebastianFlückiger The example above will listen to all user defaults because I passed in `nil` as the last argument to `addObserver:selector:name:object:` which means I don't care who is firing the notification. If I only wanted to listen to a specific user defaults instance when I would have to pass it into that method as the `object`. `NSNotification` also has an `object` property so you can check where a notification came from when you recieve it.

Comment: @deanWombourne i just found out that extensions do not trigger the group notification. going to try MMWormhole for it.

Comment: @SebastianFlückiger They might only trigger notifications within the extension - you probably won't get a corresponding notification in the main app. sigh. I've never heard of MMWormHole but it looks interesting. Good luck!